# Need real life bivariate datasets with outliers that can be modelled by sum of exponential models

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, data.gov, uses-of-open-data, large-datasets

I need real life bivariate datasets, with authentic sources, with  with the following characteristics:

1. Data can be modelled by the non-linear relationships of the form

yi = α0 + α1* e^(β* ti) + εi,

or, yi = α1* e^(β1* ti) + α2* e^(β2* ti) + εi

Here the parameters α's and  β's  may be positive or negative as well and $\epsilon_i$'s are iid random errors. Common real life examples may be found in exponential decay or growth data.

2. The data set **must include Outliers/Unusual observations** as I want to perform **Robust estimation**.
3. Proper authentic source of the data set is needed.

Please help me in finding such real life data sets.